# Regular Expression to match a specific string or a digit

Tags: java, regex

I am using java programming language.
I want to write a regular expression which would match a `specific string(e.g. boy)` or a digit`(from 5-8)` at the start of the string.
The successful input shall only be :

1. boy ....
2. 7 ....   (here 7 can be replaced by 5,6,8)

How to do this?

In all other cases, the return value shall be false.Any solution or suggestion will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(boy|[5-8])
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group (boy|[5-8])
1st Alternative: boy
boy matches the characters boy literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative: [5-8]
[5-8] match a single character present in the list below
5-8 a single character in the range between 5 and 8
```